# How to remove trailing zeros after decimal in Elixir/Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a list of numbers (float): `[1.0, 3.0, 0.25, 0.125]`

How do I format these numbers in the Phoenix template so that 1.0 and 3.0 can be shown as 1 and 3 respectively, while 0.25 and 0.125 are shown as it is.

Please note, these numbers are coming from database.

I couldn't find anything with Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might use [`Kernel.round/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#round/1) and `Kernel.==/2` to check if the float value is actually an integer.

```rb
Enum.map([1.0, 3.0, 0.25, 0.125], &if round(&1) == &1, do: round(&1), else: &1)
#⇒ [1, 3, 0.25, 0.125]
```

*Sidenote:* this is a very rare case when it’s mandatory to use `==` and not strict `===`.

---

Of course, one might convert everything to strings and replace trailing `~r/\.0+\z/` with an empty string, but I find this too kludgy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Decimal.reduce/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#reduce/1):

```elixir
Enum.map(
  [1.0, 3.0, 0.25, 0.125],
  &(&1 |> Decimal.from_float() |> Decimal.reduce() |> Decimal.to_string())
)
```

Output:

```elixir
["1", "3", "0.25", "0.125"]
```

`Decimal` is not in the standard library, so you will need to add `{:decimal, "~> 1.0"}` to `mix.exs`.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal.reduce has been deprecated.
At least from v2.0.0, you need to use.

Decimal.normalize(value)

Decimal.normalize(Decimal.new("1.00"))
will ouput Decimal with value 1

Decimal.normalize(Decimal.new("1.01"))
will output Decimal with 1.01